# How to compile ocaml to native code

Tags: compilation, ocaml, native

i'm really interested learning ocaml, it fast (they said it could be compiled to native code) and it's functional. So i tried to code something easy like enabling mysql event scheduler.

```
#load "unix.cma";;
#directory "+mysql";;
#load "mysql.cma";;
let db = Mysql.quick_connect
  ~user:"username"
  ~password:"userpassword"
  ~database:"databasename"();;
let sql =
    "SET GLOBAL EVENT_SCHEDULER=1;"
    in
    (Mysql.exec db sql);;
```

It work fine on ocaml interpreter, but when i was trying to compile it to native (i'm using ubuntu karmic), neither of these command worked

```
ocamlopt -o mysqleventon mysqleventon.ml unix.cmxa mysql.cmxa
ocamlopt -o mysqleventon mysqleventon.ml unix.cma mysql.cma
```

i also tried

```
ocamlc -c mysqleventon.ml unix.cma mysql.cma
```

all of them resulting same message

```
File "mysqleventon.ml", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: Syntax error
```

Then i tried to remove the "# load", so the code goes like this

```
let db = Mysql.quick_connect
  ~user:"username"
  ~password:"userpassword"
  ~database:"databasename"();;
let sql =
    "SET GLOBAL EVENT_SCHEDULER=1;"
    in
    (Mysql.exec db sql);;
```

The ocamlopt resulting message

```
File "mysqleventon.ml", line 1, characters 9-28:
Error: Unbound value Mysql.quick_connect
```

I hope someone could tell me, where did i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Just a comment: you don't need the Printf.sprintf in the code you show.

Comment: I modified it from net (forgot the address) as my first attempt on database. I've tried your sugestion, and you are right, so i remove "Printf.sprintf" part from the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`#load` and `#directory` are the [toplevel directives](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-312/manual023.html#toc82). They instruct ocaml where to find mysql and unix libraries. For native (or bytecode) compilation remove those directives and replace them with corresponding [command-line flags](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-312/manual025.html#toc92). `#load` maps just to the file name and `#directory` to `-I`. So for bytecode:

```
ocamlc unix.cma -I +mysql mysql.cma mysqleventon.ml -o mysqleventon
```

Native code:

```
ocamlopt unix.cmxa -I +mysql mysql.cmxa -o mysqleventon mysqleventon.ml
```

NB: [.cmxa is for native code, .cma for bytecode.](http://mirror.ocamlcore.org/ocaml-tutorial.org/filenames.html) Also the order of filenames on command-line matters.

Or better use ocamlfind and don't worry about paths and extensions :

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt -package unix,mysql -linkpkg mysqleventon.ml -o mysqleventon
```

Comment: The command works and your explanation is a real help. Thank you.