# Ocaml topfind lwt

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to use lwt module with Ocaml

```
%cat .ocamlinit
#use "topfind";;  
#require "lwt.simple-top";; 
#require "lwt.syntax";;
#require "findlib";;
#require "num.core";;
#load "nums.cma";;
#load "unix.cma";;
#camlp4o;;
open Lwt;;
open Lwt_io;;
```

When I try to use any Lwt API using this command to build
"ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind myFile.native"

I receive this error:
"Error: Unbound module Lwt"

When I type in terminal %ocaml it loads successfully and i can use Lwt.API's

What is going on? any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

ocamlbuild doesn't read .ocamlinit, it is purely for toplevel (i.e. ocaml).
In order to compile lwt-dependent project you will need to specify dependencies, e.g. :

```
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -package lwt myFile.native
```

See also [How to compile ocaml to native code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672577/how-to-compile-ocaml-to-native-code/2673871#2673871)

Comment: I might then put that in the _tag file

Comment: Also what does top level means?

Comment: toplevel = repl in other languages. An interactive shell where you can evaluate snippets of code and immediately see a result.

Comment: Thanks. you mean the interpreter that execute the code line by line.